# How to bind a variable to ResourceManager.getString() in Flex using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, localization, air, desktop-application

Those day I am trying to find a way to bind a variable to a localised resource and I really do not have any result.

The situation is the following:
I have a class ComponentTypes.as, which contains some public variables of type string.
I want those variables to be bound to translated resource:

```
package Model
{
    import mx.resources.IResourceManager;
    import mx.resources.ResourceManager;

    public class ComponentTypes
    {
        private static var resourceManagerInstance:IResourceManager = ResourceManager.getInstance();

        //Areas and Volumes
        [Bindable]
        public static var HEATED_AREA:String = resourceManagerInstance.getString('app','phpx.componenttypes.heatedareas');
        [Bindable]
        public static var HEATED_VOLUME:String = resourceManagerInstance.getString('app','phpx.componenttypes.heatedvolumes');
    }
}
```

However those variables are not updated when the locale is changed. This is clear, as they are not currently bound.

So my question is: Is there a way that I can bound those variables to he ResourceManager class, so they are updated when the locale is changed?

Comment: Have a look at [IResourceManager.update()](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/resources/IResourceManager.html#update%28%29); might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Nope, it does not do the trick. The documentation says: "This causes binding expressions to re-evaluate...", however I do not have binding expression. That is exactly my question - how to bind the variables to the resource manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made it work:

```
private function getResource(host:IResourceManager):String
{
    var result:String = '';

    result = host.getString('text', 'test');

    return result;
}

protected function windowedapplication1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    BindingUtils.bindProperty(this,'bindedVariable', resourceManager, {name:'getString', getter:getResource});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting an object using the `object = value` notation is run *only once*, when execution hits that point in the code. In the event of a `static` variable, that occurs the first time the variable is called (I may be wrong and it may be the first time the Class is called or imported, end result here is the same, though).

So you can't bind that way. The way binding works is when a `Bindable` variable is physically set, it dispatches an event that objects which are binded to it are listening for. What you do there is set the variable once and never touch it again.

You can bind one of two ways:

1. In MXML using the `{{ property }}` notation
2. In AS3 using [`BindingUtils`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html). `BindingUtils` attaches an internal event listener (i.e. you don't have to attach it yourself) and updates the provided property. I am unsure it will work with a `static` object, however.

I did check the source code for `mx.resources.IResourceManager#getString()` and verified it is a bindable object, so you are good there.

Comment: I perfectly understand why I can not bind with     object=value notation. Your explanation is great! I also understand how to bind it using MXML, however this is not what I need. The thing is that I can not achieve the binding with     BindingUtils. Can you please help me with a code example. I would be grateful!